# Where can I find a list of english part of speech constraints?

Tags: nlp, part-of-speech

I'm looking for a list of English part of speech sequencing rules (e.g. "a determiner cannot be followed by a verb"). 
Thought it would be easy but I couldn't find an actual list of more than several examples.
Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of make a "list of POS constraints" lies in the fact that those constrants will mainly depends on discourse domain.

I think you can face it from a n-gram approach. You can make POS tagging over a specific corpus (wikipedia articles for certain topic for example) then generate 2-grams or 3-grams (using grams of words) and calculate their frequencies, so you will get the most/less frequent POS combinantions. Finally, you can think about those POS combinations which not even appeared in the frecuency list, such sequences may be called "part of speech constraints".